# MYSQL How to get the last second word from String

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to split the string by *Firstname*, *MiddleName* and *LastName* but I'm having trouble getting the MiddleName. Here is my query:

```
select
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(admin, ' ', 1) as 'FirstName',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(admin, ' ', +1) as 'MiddleName',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(admin, ' ', -1) as 'LastName'
FROM fullname
```

My table
| id | FullName             |
| -- | ---------------------|
| 1  | Kim Paulo D. Ercillo |
| 2  | Levi T. Marquez      |
| 3  | Brian W. Smiley      |

Desired output
| FirstName| Middle Name| Last Name   |
|----------| ---------- |-------------|
| Kim      | D          |  Ercillo    |
| Levi     | T          |   Marquez   |
|  Brian   | W          |  Smiley     |

Result I'm getting
| FirstName| Middle Name| Last Name   |
|----------|------------|-------------|
| Kim      | Kim        |  Ercillo    |
| Levi     |Levi        |   Marquez   |
|  Brian   |  Brian     |  Smiley     |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(admin, ' ', 1) as 'FirstName',
  TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(admin, ' ', -2), ' ', 1)) as 'MiddleName',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(admin, ' ', -1) as 'LastName'
FROM
  fullname
```